# How to add some text value in cell

Tags: google-sheets

I am newbie in Google Spreadsheets, but I would like to know how I can select a column with values and add in every selected cell some text, i.e

> `<KB>` .

Is possible to perform via Regex or maybe some kind of macros?

Answer (score 1):

Insert a new column just to the left (or right) of the column you want to change.
In the top cell of the new column (Say it's cell G23 and your data is in F23:F32) put i:
=F32 & "

With only G23 selected, pull down on the little square on the lower right to fill the formula down to G32 - This will propogate the formula down, with the row # incrementing.

Make sure that G23:G32 looks like you want it to look, if so, then

Copy the range G23:G32

Select cell F23

"Paste Special" (under the Edit menu) and choose "Paste Values Only"

Ta Da!

Comment: or shift+ctrl+v to paste values instantly

Answer (score 0):

To add text to a value you need to use another column, say your column A has the values, you want to add , in B2 (assuming B2 is a header) just enter:

```
=A2&"<KB>"
```

or if you want a space in between

```
=A2&" <KB>"
```

So, if you have in A2 "1024" you will get:

```
1024 <KB>
```